# openlayers3 restore original style of specific feature

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a map with LineStrings. There are different types of lines, the vector layer contains a style-class and the styles are dynamically loaded via ajax, i.e. stroke color and width.

My map is interactive, I can select some line strings to assign attributes in my data base. When I select a line string with the mouse, I set the color of the line to red to visualize all selected line strings on the map.

Now the question: If I un-select a line string, how can I restore the original style for this specific feature (line string)?

A simplified page can be found here:
http://mapit.ch/test/map_line_style.html

It uses "Geo Admin API" which is based on openlayers 3.
Geo Admin API is used to show different maps from Switzerland, this is removed in the example above. The only function which is used from the API is ga.style.StylesFromLiterals(data)
"data" is the json file with the styles, retrieved via ajax (the style file can be changed interactively by the user)

The vector layer is also retrieved via json, each feature has its stlye-class, as a reference to the style file.

I didn't manage to run this in a fiddle, because of the ajax requests and the API which requires a license.

Comment: Question : For Selected LineString(feature) whether u create a separate Style Object?

Comment: Put your code in a fiddle or show the relevant part.

Comment: Hope, the extended description above an the link with the example helps. Thanks.